# Playing 2 timelines one after another with WPF media-element

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard, media-player

My problem is fairly simple and very easy to reproduce.

I am trying to play the first song for 5 seconds at the start and the second song for 10 seconds after 6 seconds have passed, using `MediaTimeLine` and a storyboard.

Here is the code, just open a new WPF application and copy the XAML and the Code to reproduce it. Oh, and make sure to change the path for 2 songs you got locally in your machine..

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <MediaElement Name="MediaElementObject1" />
    <Button Width="100" Height="100" Margin="26,48,391,171" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private readonly Storyboard animation = new Storyboard();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var mediaUri1 = new Uri(@"C:\MediaExamplesForWork\Sting - Sting At The Movies - 07 - Shape OF My Heart (Leon & Three Of Hearts).mp3");
            var mediaUri2 = new Uri(@"C:\MediaExamplesForWork\Desireless - Voyage Voyage.mp3");
            animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

            var timeline1 = new MediaTimeline
            {
                Name = "a1",
                BeginTime = TimeSpan.Zero, 
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
                Source = mediaUri1,
                FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd
            };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(timeline1, MediaElementObject1);
            animation.Children.Add(timeline1);

            var timeline2 = new MediaTimeline
            {
                Name = "a2",
                BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6),
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                Source = mediaUri2,
                FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd
            };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(timeline2, MediaElementObject1);
            animation.Children.Add(timeline2);

            animation.Begin();    
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            animation.SeekAlignedToLastTick(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        }
    }
}
```

You will notice the 1st song will not play, the 2nd will play.
if you remark the 2nd song - the first one will play.

How to fix it so both will play according to the begin time and duration already set in the example code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems impossible for media-element to handle two media-time-lines.

I had to add another media-element which I don't like.. but this is how I end up solving this problem..

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <MediaElement Name="MediaElementObject1" />
    <MediaElement Name="MediaElementObject2" />
    <Button Width="100" Height="100" Margin="26,48,391,171" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace WpfApp1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private readonly Storyboard animation = new Storyboard();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var mediaUri1 = new Uri(@"C:\MediaExamplesForWork\Sting - Sting At The Movies - 07 - Shape OF My Heart (Leon & Three Of Hearts).mp3");
        var mediaUri2 = new Uri(@"C:\MediaExamplesForWork\Desireless - Voyage Voyage.mp3");

        animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);


        var timeline1 = new MediaTimeline
        {
            Name = "a1",
            BeginTime = TimeSpan.Zero, 
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
            Source = mediaUri1,
            FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd
        };
        Storyboard.SetTarget(timeline1, MediaElementObject1);
        animation.Children.Add(timeline1);


        var timeline2 = new MediaTimeline
        {
            Name = "a2",
            BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6),
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
            Source = mediaUri2,
            FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd
        };
        Storyboard.SetTarget(timeline2, MediaElementObject2);
        animation.Children.Add(timeline2);

        animation.Begin();

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        animation.SeekAlignedToLastTick(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(13));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the BeginTime property of TimeLine does not affect the start time of the media file. The media file will always  starts at position 0. With BeginTime=6 and Duration=10, you will see 6 seconds of nothing, then the video will play from the BEGINNING for 10 seconds. Using MediaTimeline does not seem to be a valid way of sepcifying the start time of the video clip. Hope someone can prove me wrong.

The other approach is set the Position property then call Play, then use a timer to monitor when the end time is reached. It seems a bit cludgy, but it works. I haven't seen a better way. You would then also start the second clip in the same way.

Comment: Please, use formatting and reduce the number of extra phrases - it's much easier to read short and well-structured answers.